# From Bayesian Network To Correlation Matrix

Tags: probability, bayesian, correlation

I have a Bayesian network where the edges are likelihood estimations from features {x1,...,xn}. How can I estimate the covariance matrix for x from this Bayesian net? I understand that we normally use a correlation matrix to create the Bayesian network, but I need to do vice versa: I have a Bayesian network and I want to calculate the corresponding correlation matrix. Is conditional probability (likelihood estimate) the same as correlation?

Answer (score 1):

If, by Bayesian network, you mean a Bayesian network generated from an directed acyclic graph (DAG), then this is straight forward.  Since you are asking about a correlation matrix, you are assuming linearity and normality.  A DAG, converted to linear links between nodes and normally distributed variables, is equivalent to a series of structural equations, i.e. SEM.  The basic rules of path tracing of SEM will generate the predicted covariance (thus correlation) matrix given this network.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Yes, i mean a DAG. can use from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751950/from-correlation-coefficient-to-conditional-probability instead SEM.is a DAG the show of conditional probability? if yes, so we can get a equation between conditional probability and correlation.